# Error while downloading file with "." in name in RoR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, download

When I download a file that contains `"."` in its name my code throws an exception:

```
No route matches "/test/download/File%201.0%20BETA.docx"
```

The file name is: "*File 1.0 BETA.docx*"

Here is my code for downloading file in my controller file:

```
  def download
    path = params[:path]
    path = "#{Rails.root}/public/data/" + path
    send_file(path+"."+params[:format])
  end
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: How do you [protect against](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file) some clown supplying a `params[:path]=../../../config/database` and `params[:format]=yaml`? If they get the number of `../` correct, this sure looks like it'll hand over your database config, or any other file on your server with a period somewhere in the name and correct permissions.

Comment: Are you sure the failure in your current code is due to the `.`? I'd wager first that the `%20` aren't being decoded and the call to `send_file()` is trying to find a file named `File@201.0%20BETA.docx`. You may need to URL-decode the parameter first.

Comment: @sarnold: I'm sure its because of ".". When I remove/replace "." by "_" it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by your routes not supporting multiple "." in the path. For example, if your routes look like this:

```
'/test/download/:path.:extension'
```

Then that will break if the filename contains more then one "."

Instead you could do a routing like this:

```
'/test/download/*path.:extension'
```

That will make sure that multiple "." is functioning